# How to continuously execute an application with cmd with Windows Server?

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2003, shell-script

this is my requirement:

I need to execute an endless script continuously. The script never ends by itself but if someone closes it I need to launch it again (can be a delay between the close and the restart if needed, it's not a problem having it stopped for 1 hour).

I also need the script running when there is no one logged on the computer.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You could set it up with task scheduler to run every 5 minutes and to not launch if already running.

Comment: With which schedule? I thought on that but I need to give it a schedule and it cannot be "when the computer starts".

Comment: As @Shevek says.  Through Task Scheduler, have it run every 5 minutes, but not run if it already is.  That way it will only start if not already running.  Same schedule will start the job if the machine is rebooted. If the job needs to access the network or a share, you may have to set it to run a a specific user account other than system

Comment: In Windows 2003 server is not like this. When you create a Schedule you say if you want it daily, at computer start, etc. If you say computer start you cannot say "repeat task". If you say daily you can repeat the task each 5 minuts but if you reboot the machine the task won't start until the time you have set on the daily schedule. So I still have no solution :(

Comment: Is there not an option for "start if trigger is missed" or similar?